# oracle sql tuning：　IO requst or IO bytes ,which should I prefer?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am tuning sql now.

- Oracle 12.1
- BLock size :16K
- DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT: 64

```
SYSSTATS_MAIN   CPUSPEEDNW  2698.14241486068
SYSSTATS_MAIN   IOSEEKTIM   10
SYSSTATS_MAIN   IOTFRSPEED  4096
SYSSTATS_MAIN   SREADTIM    0.121
SYSSTATS_MAIN   MREADTIM    1.799
SYSSTATS_MAIN   CPUSPEED    2811
SYSSTATS_MAIN   MBRC    2
SYSSTATS_MAIN   MAXTHR  597475328
SYSSTATS_MAIN   SLAVETHR    4006912
```

I have two plans.

plan 1 is with hint USE_NL (using index in nest loop):

- DB time : 9s
- IO request: 44K
- IO bytes: 1G

plan 2 is default, without any hint (using table access full in hash join):

- DB time : 46s
- IO request: 7254
- IO bytes: 4G

I think I should choose plan 1 because Its DB time is short and IO bytes is small.

But I am worried about that the IO request is so much more than plan 2. Is it a problem which can impact other processes?

Comment: Please edit your question style (now it looks ugly).

Comment: I consider it natural that using nested loops results in more, but smaller I/O requests. So, yes, I'd go with the first plan, too, if 46 seconds are an issue for you. If this is not an issue, I wouldn't use hints. Anyway, it's rare nowadays for Oracle to choose an execution plan that is much inferior to another. Maybe the statistics are out-dated? In that case gathering new statistics might already solve your issues.